# Image Gallery carousel from right to left direction not working when changing css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an image gallery and it works fine for the English version but i need to replicate same for the other version of the website and need to make it work in RTL direction. When i css 'direction:rtl' it breaks the thumbnail script and  next | prev navigation doesn't work anymore.

I tried to change many a thing but none seems to work i even made some minor changes to the gallery.js but that didn't even fix the issue.

I am not sure how to create a make everything work for thumbnail carousel when direction:rtl.

I need this for Arbic version of website and Arabic is RTL not like English which is LTR.

Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/f4XDj/ 
**Updated Link** http://jsfiddle.net/f4XDj/1/

Actual gallery sample link http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/

Partial HTML Code

```
        <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
            <div class="rg-thumbs">
                <!-- Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                    <div class="es-nav">
                        <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                        <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="es-carousel">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-large="images/3.jpg" alt="image03" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-large="images/4.jpg" alt="image04" data-description="My spirits to attend this double voice accorded" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" data-large="images/5.jpg" alt="image05" data-description="And down I laid to list the sad-tuned tale" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" data-large="images/6.jpg" alt="image06" data-description="Ere long espied a fickle maid full pale" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" data-large="images/7.jpg" alt="image07" data-description="Tearing of papers, breaking rings a-twain" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" data-large="images/8.jpg" alt="image08" data-description="Storming her world with sorrow's wind and rain" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" data-large="images/9.jpg" alt="image09" data-description="Upon her head a platted hive of straw" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" data-large="images/10.jpg" alt="image10" data-description="Which fortified her visage from the sun" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" data-large="images/11.jpg" alt="image11" data-description="Whereon the thought might think sometime it saw" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" data-large="images/12.jpg" alt="image12" data-description="The carcass of beauty spent and done" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" data-large="images/13.jpg" alt="image13" data-description="Time had not scythed all that youth begun" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" data-large="images/14.jpg" alt="image14" data-description="Nor youth all quit; but, spite of heaven's fell rage" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/15.jpg" data-large="images/15.jpg" alt="image15" data-description="Some beauty peep'd through lattice of sear'd age" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/16.jpg" data-large="images/16.jpg" alt="image16" data-description="Oft did she heave her napkin to her eyne" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/17.jpg" data-large="images/17.jpg" alt="image17" data-description="Which on it had conceited characters" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/18.jpg" data-large="images/18.jpg" alt="image18" data-description="Laundering the silken figures in the brine" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/19.jpg" data-large="images/19.jpg" alt="image19" data-description="That season'd woe had pelleted in tears" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/20.jpg" data-large="images/20.jpg" alt="image20" data-description="And often reading what contents it bears" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/21.jpg" data-large="images/21.jpg" alt="image21" data-description="As often shrieking undistinguish'd woe" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/22.jpg" data-large="images/22.jpg" alt="image22" data-description="In clamours of all size, both high and low" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/23.jpg" data-large="images/23.jpg" alt="image23" data-description="Sometimes her levell'd eyes their carriage ride" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/24.jpg" data-large="images/24.jpg" alt="image24" data-description="As they did battery to the spheres intend" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
            </div><!-- rg-thumbs -->
        </div><!-- rg-gallery -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I write new rule for a your example from tympanus and for me working:

```
.rg-caption p {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

and I delete this rule:

```
 .rg-caption{
        text-align: center;
    }
```

so if you would change a direction in carousel you must change this part:

```
$navPrev.bind('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
_navigate( 'left' );
return false;
});
$navNext.bind('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
_navigate( 'right' );
return false;
});
// add touchwipe events on the large image wrapper
$imgWrapper.touchwipe({
wipeLeft : function() {
_navigate( 'right' );
},
wipeRight : function() {
_navigate( 'left' );
},
preventDefaultEvents: false
});
$(document).bind('keyup.rgGallery', function( event ) {
if (event.keyCode == 39)
_navigate( 'right' );
else if (event.keyCode == 37)
_navigate( 'left' );
});
}
},
_navigate = function( dir ) {
// navigate through the large images
if( anim ) return false;
anim = true;
if( dir === 'right' ) {
if( current + 1 >= itemsCount )
current = 0;
else
++current;
}
else if( dir === 'left' ) {
if( current - 1 < 0 )
current = itemsCount - 1;
else
--current;
}
```

Comment: I have done this part already this will only align caption in of image in RTL direction if i am not wrong and this is how is was working on my i only want thumbnail carousel to show up in RTL direction and navigation to work IN RTL direction...